# Multiprocessing Error

Tags: python, multiprocessing

On Windows platform these two lines cause Python code execution to run in infinite loop with every loop starting from the beginning of the script:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
manager=mp.Manager()
```

It runs fine on Mac. What would be a reason?  It successfully imports `import multiprocessing as mp`. But on `manager=mp.Manager()` it breaks (with no errors) and jumps back to the first line of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows, you have to protect calls to `multiprocessing` with `if __name__ == "__main__":`. See [here](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/multiprocessing.html#windows) for details on why this is required. This should work fine:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

if __name__ == "__main__":
    manager=mp.Manager()
```

**Edit:**

Note that putting your `multiprocessing` code inside functions you call from the `if` block is ok, too. Like this:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def func(x):
   print("Got %s" % (x,))

def main():
  p = multiprocessing.Pool()
  results = p.map(func, range(0,5))

if __name__ == "__main__":
  manager = mp.Manager()
  main()
```

Comment: So I have to move import into `if name==main` scope?

Comment: @Sputnix No problem. Just note that **all** your calls that involve creating a new process via `multiprocessing` (like creating a `Pool` or `Process`) need to be done inside the `if __name__ ...` block.

Comment: Should I put `pool.map_async(functName, ['arg1','arg2','arg3'])` inside of `if __name__=="__main__"` too?

Comment: @Sputnix Yep, that too.

Comment: And where do I declare `functName()` function that is called by `pool.map_async(functName, argList)`..... inside of `if __name__=="__main__"? Isn't it a mess?

Comment: @Sputnix No, `functName()` can be defined outside of the `if` guard. Also keep in mind it's ok to call functions inside your `if` block to organize the everything better, if you want. I edited my answer to illustrate that.

Comment: I am using multiprocessing dictionary variable declared with: `import multiprocessing as mp; manager=mp.Manager(); poolDict=manager.dict()` Can `poolDict` variable accessed from outside of `if __name__=='__main__'`?

Comment: @Sputnix You should explicitly pass `poolDict` to the functions you're calling via `multiprocessing`. You can do this with `map`/`map_async` by using `functools.partial`. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24293334/2073595) for an example of this.