# Sharing a counter with multiprocessing.Pool

Tags: python, python-3.x, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I'd like to use `multiprocessing.Value` + `multiprocessing.Lock` to share a counter between separate processes.  For example:

```
import itertools as it
import multiprocessing

def func(x, val, lock):
    for i in range(x):
        i ** 2
    with lock:
        val.value += 1
        print('counter incremented to:', val.value)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    v = multiprocessing.Value('i', 0)
    lock = multiprocessing.Lock()

    with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
        pool.starmap(func, ((i, v, lock) for i in range(25)))
    print(counter.value())
```

This will throw the following exception:

> RuntimeError: Synchronized objects should only be shared between
>   processes through inheritance

What I am most confused by is that a related (albeit not completely analogous) pattern works with `multiprocessing.Process()`:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    v = multiprocessing.Value('i', 0)
    lock = multiprocessing.Lock()

    procs = [multiprocessing.Process(target=func, args=(i, v, lock))
             for i in range(25)]
    for p in procs: p.start()
    for p in procs: p.join()
```

Now, I recognize that these are two different markedly things:

- the first example uses a number of worker processes equal to `cpu_count()`, and splits an iterable `range(25)` between them
- the second example creates 25 worker processes and tasks each with one input

That said: how can I share an instance with `pool.starmap()` (or `pool.map()`) in this manner?

I've seen similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9856196/7954504), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2080660/7954504), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24293035/7954504), but those approaches doesn't seem to be suited to `.map()`/`.starmap()`, regarldess of whether `Value` uses `ctypes.c_int`.

---

I realize that this approach technically works:

```
def func(x):
    for i in range(x):
        i ** 2
    with lock:
        v.value += 1
        print('counter incremented to:', v.value)

v = None
lock = None

def set_global_counter_and_lock():
    """Egh ... """
    global v, lock
    if not any((v, lock)):
        v = multiprocessing.Value('i', 0)
        lock = multiprocessing.Lock()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Each worker process will call `initializer()` when it starts.
    with multiprocessing.Pool(initializer=set_global_counter_and_lock) as pool:
        pool.map(func, range(25))
```

Is this really the best-practices way of going about this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `RuntimeError` you get when using `Pool` is because arguments for pool-methods are pickled before being send over a (pool-internal) queue to the worker processes.
Which pool-method you are trying to use is irrelevant here. This doesn't happen when you just use `Process` because there is no queue involved. You can reproduce the error just with `pickle.dumps(multiprocessing.Value('i', 0))`.

Your last code snippet doesn't work how you think it works. You are not *sharing* a `Value`, you are recreating independent counters for every child process.

In case you were on Unix and used the default start-method "fork", you would be done with just **not** passing the shared objects as arguments into the pool-methods.
Your child-processes would inherit the globals through forking. With process-start-methods "spawn" (default Windows and [macOS with Python 3.8+](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#multiprocessing)) or "forkserver", you'll have to use the `initializer` during `Pool`
instantiation, to let the child-processes inherit the shared objects.

Note, you don't need an extra `multiprocessing.Lock` here, because `multiprocessing.Value` comes by default with an internal one you can use.

```
import os
from multiprocessing import Pool, Value #, set_start_method


def func(x):
    for i in range(x):
        assert i == i
        with cnt.get_lock():
            cnt.value += 1
            print(f'{os.getpid()} | counter incremented to: {cnt.value}\n')


def init_globals(counter):
    global cnt
    cnt = counter


if __name__ == '__main__':

    # set_start_method('spawn')

    cnt = Value('i', 0)
    iterable = [10000 for _ in range(10)]

    with Pool(initializer=init_globals, initargs=(cnt,)) as pool:
        pool.map(func, iterable)

    assert cnt.value == 100000
```

Probably worth noting as well is that you don't need the counter to be *shared* in all cases.
If you just need to keep track of how often something has happened in total, an option would be to keep separate worker-local counters during computation which you sum up at the end.
This could result in a significant performance improvement for frequent counter updates for which you don't need synchronization during the parallel computation itself.